Upload >400mb binary file to databricks workspace
Need upload to local workspace folder with .bin extension.
It is required to have it locally.
How can I upload that .bin file to local storage of my workspace?

I tried load from DBFS, but loading files over 265mb is not allowed with cluster.

I tried to upload manually but failed with same error "OSError: [Errno5] Input/output error".

Also i tried to compress file but since this is binary file compression didn't change significantly file size and manual upload failed as previous attempt.


